# How to segment the image with reflecting light

Tags: opencv, segment

Now  I want to segment the parking slot lines in the images liking the following  picture,but the reflecting lights severely affect the threshold value.anybody can help me to find a good way to segment the parking slot lines,thanks very much.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reflecting lights are always on the same positions, you can make a mask of these and do an AND function on the inverted mask.
After the AND the lights will be black and you can proceed with a normal threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Your solution is very good idea if the reflecting always on the same position.But in reality it"s not,because the camera mounted on the car,the reflecting block will be happened in the different place,Now I have tried to filter the reflecting in the  frequency domain,then using the morphology operations to address it.The result is good.